# Spring Boot WebCLient accept Self Signed Certificate, but not with InsecureTrustManagerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, reactive-programming, reactor-netty

I'm trying to build a REST client using Spring Boot and utilizing `WebClient`, however I'm conflicted when trying to config HTTPS call to a REST API.

When using `RestTemplate`, I was able to get self signed certificate working by using `TrustSelfSignedStrategy()`, thus even when the certificate is self signed, it is still being validated for its hostname, expiry date, etc.

In `WebClient`, so far I only found the way self signed certificate is by utilizing `InsecureTrustManagerFactory`, however this will cause the whole validation to be skipped as well, effectively void the purpose of using HTTPS in the first place.

As quoted from [Netty documentations](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/util/InsecureTrustManagerFactory.html):

> An insecure TrustManagerFactory that trusts all X.509 certificates without any verification.
>
> NOTE: Never use this TrustManagerFactory in production. It is purely for testing purposes, and thus it is very insecure.

Is there any way I can use self signed certificate in `WebClient` without having to dismantle all the verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a self signed certificate. What you need to do is add the self signed certificate into a java keystore and  load it into your application by getting the keystore and transforming it into a TrustManager. Afterword you can supply the TrustManager to the SslContextBuilder which is needed for configuring the WebClient based on Netty. See below for an example:

```
Path truststorePath = Paths.get(/path/to/your/truststore)
InputStream truststoreInputStream = Files.newInputStream(truststorePath, StandardOpenOption.READ)

KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
truststore.load(truststoreInputStream, truststorePassword);

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(truststore);

SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
        .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
        .build()

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .secure(sslSpec -> sslSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build()
```

Comment: I reckon this method still enforce all the other verification; hostname, expiry, etc? I remember changing to `InsecureTrustManagerFactory` due to this can't seem to use self signed; however after some thought it might be caused by other things. I'll get back when I try this again. Thanks btw!

Comment: a little bit odd; This is due to the Certificate was not correctly prepared (hostname and CN was not matched - hence missing my whole purpose of this question), so I have some difficulty connecting it in dev env. I'm trying to test in pre-prod env with more proper certificate, hopefully today since I have requested the access from yesterday

Comment: result just comes in; it works. I will mark this as accepted answer, thank you very much!